# Regularization and feature scaling in online learning?

Tags: machine-learning, normalization, regularization, online-algorithms

Let's say I have a logistic regression classifier. In normal batch learning, I'd have a regularizer term to prevent overfitting and keep my weights small. I'd also normalize and scale my features.

In an online learning setting, I'm getting a continuous stream of data. I do a gradient descent update with each example and then discard it. Am I supposed to use feature scaling and regularization term in online learning? If yes, how can I do that? For example, I don't have a set of training data to scale against. I also don't have validation set to tune my regularization parameter. If no, why not?

In my online learning, I get a stream of examples continuously. For each new example, I do a prediction. Then in the next time step, I get the actual target and do the gradient descent update.

Answer (score 9):

The open-source project [vowpal wabbit](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit) includes an implementation of online SGD which is enhanced by on the fly (online) computation of 3 additional factors affecting the weight updates. These factors can be enabled/disabled by their respective command line options (by default all three are turned on, the `--sgd` option, turns them all off, i.e: falls-back on "classic" SGD).

The 3 SGD enhancing options are:

- `--normalized` updates adjusted for scale of each feature
- `--adaptive` uses adaptive gradient (AdaGrad) (Duchi, Hazan, Singer)
- `--invariant` importance aware updates (Karampatziakis, Langford)

Together, they ensure that the online learning process does a 3-way automatic compensation/adjustment for:

- per-feature scaling (large vs small values)
- per-feature learning rate decay based on feature importance
- per feature adaptive learning rate adjustment for feature prevalence/rarity in examples

The upshot is that there's no need to pre-normalize or scale different features to make the learner less biased and more effective.

In addition, *vowpal wabbit* also implements online regularization via truncated gradient descent with the regularization options:

- `--l1` (L1-norm)
- `--l2` (L2-norm)

My experience with these enhancements on multiple data-sets, was that they significantly improved model accuracy and smoother convergence when each of them was introduced into the code.

Here are some academic papers for more detail related to these enhancements:

- [Online Importance Weight Aware Updates](http://lowrank.net/nikos/pubs/liw.pdf) by Nikos Karampatziakis and John Langford + [Slides of talk about this paper](http://lowrank.net/nikos/pubs/uai11_slides.pdf)
- [Sparse online learning via truncated gradient](http://hunch.net/~jl/projects/interactive/sparse_online/paper_sparseonline.pdf) by John Langford, Lihong Li, and Tong Zhang
- [Adaptive Subgradient Methods for Online Learning and Stochastic Optimization](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume12/duchi11a/duchi11a.pdf) by John Duchi, Elad Hazan, Yoram Singer

Comment: Arielf - If you turn off the three enhancements (via --sgd) is the sgd that is being done shown on slide 11 of https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/v6.1_tutorial.pdf so that then power_t and initial_t become relevant?

Comment: B_miner: as far as I understand `--power_t` and `--initial_t` are global (not per feature) independent options.  `--sgd` only reverts to the "classic" SGD. IOW: `--sgd` only cancels `--invariant`, `--normalized`, and `--adaptive` (which imply separate, per-feature learning-rates)

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to do these updates in a parallel asynchronous fashion (as is done in asynchronous SGD)? It seems VW with multiple workers averages each worker's model at the end of each pass. Any papers/software pointers on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This paper describes a technique for online regularization which they apply to various algorithms, including logistic regression: http://ai.stanford.edu/~chuongdo/papers/proximal.pdf

Answer (score 1):

yes you certainly need regularisation... it also helps the gradient descent ( and initialise learning rate to 1/C)

see eg SGD-QN paper http://leon.bottou.org/papers bottou's papers

you haven't really explained what you mean by online learning: eg for each point do you get target value? 
I don't know how you would incorporate... searching for C ... I guess you would have multiple classifiers with different regularisation terms and track the prediction error ( before you update weights)

Comment: By online learning, I get one example and do a prediction. At the next time step, I get the actual target for my example and do a gradient descent update.

Comment: well then it should be as I suggested - you run a bunch of classifiers with different regularisation parameter and keep track of the prediction errors of each classifier.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by initialize learning rate to 1/C. What is C? Are you talking about support vector machines? I'm talking about logistic regression where the regularizer has coefficient lambda. I don't know what that has to do with the learning rate.

Comment: yes the l2 regularisation parameter, C, lambda, or whatever. its something that is mentioned in an aside in bottou's sgdqn paper, and I presume explained better somewhere else.  basically your learning rate should be the 1/curvature (inverse of Hessian) of your error surface.. now if your error surface is

Comment: Do I also need to do feature scaling? How to do that in an online setting?

Comment: cut off....  basically your learning rate should be the 1/curvature (inverse of Hessian) of your cost surface.. let E(w) be your training  error,  if your cost surface is C(w)=E(w)+ 1/2 lambda w.w, then your Hessian eigen values of C(w) are at least lambda [ I GUESS,because your E(w) in logistic regression is also convex], so I didn't really want to say that learning rate should be exactly 1/lambda, but it will depend on it, as in SGD-QN paper]

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9646/discussion-between-seanv507-and-siamii)